# Flexbox with Unordered list

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn flexbox and I really like it. I'm trying το play with dynamic widths and when I do it with `div`s it works. If I try to do it with `li`, it doesn't work as well. My code is up on [codepen](http://codepen.io/jrock2004/pen/pjvZJd).

```
div.example
  ul
    li
      | 1
    li
      | 2
    li
      | 3
    li
      | 4
    li
      | 5
    li
      | 6

div.container
  div.col
    | 1
  div.col
    | 2
  div.col
    | 3
  div.col
    | 4
  div.col
    | 5
  div.col
    | 6
```

SASS Code

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  
  .col {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1em 0;
  
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to apply the flex properties to the `<ul>`

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; <-- not needed as this is the default behavior
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Putting the properties on the `<div>` tells it to display the `<ul>` in flex, not `<li>`.

Comment: The answer is old but I wanted to ask why we need to give a ```row``` as by default the flex is row?

Comment: @localhost short answer: You don't need it, `flex-direction` is `row` by default (on desktop)

Answer (score 14):

Based on your markup, note that the `<li>` elements are the child of `<ul>`, not the `.example` division element.

```
<div class="example">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since the immediate parent of the `<li>` elements are `<ul>`, use the `flex` properties on the `<ul>` that is wrapping around the multiple `<li>` elements, instead of the outer `<div>` element:

```
.example {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1em 0;

  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGPBbg

Comment: This doesn't work within Safari 8 or 9, but it does work in Chrome. I'm having similar issues, and can't figure this out for the life of me. I've found similar pens that have this working with divs, however (https://jsfiddle.net/s1Leczfg/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Apply the "display:flex" property to the  element, as that is the direct parent of

, rather than .example class. It should flex in the horizontal direction.
Refer to [w3scchools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) docs for more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).