# Footer content not showing in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, footer

still very new to this so apologies in advance.

In my footer, the desktop view works fine. As does the landscape mobile view. Heres how it looks on  those two views

[Landscape views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0YAk.jpg)

But in mobile portrait, the social media icons are missing, where have i gone wrong?

[Portrait View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRRZy.jpg)

HTML code for my footer

```
<footer class="nav navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p>&copy; 2017 Example Example</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-snapchat"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-youtube"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

CSS for footer styling

```
footer {
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

footer p {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: right;
    font-size:35px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.fa-twitter {
    margin-right:10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fa-twitter:hover{
    color: #00aced;
}

.fa-facebook {
    margin-right:10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fa-facebook:hover{
    color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-instagram {
    margin-right:10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fa-instagram:hover{

    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #fccc63, #fbad50, #e95950, #cd486b, #8a3ab9, #4c68d7);
    color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.fa-snapchat {
    margin-right:10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fa-snapchat:hover{
    color: #fffc00;
}

.fa-youtube {
    margin-right:5px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fa-youtube:hover{
    color: #cb2027;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `ul`with the social icons simply doesn't fit into the width of the footer next to the text of the `p` tag and is pushed below into a new line (both are floated). But since the height is fixed (50px), it's hidden. Try to change the height of `footer` to sonething like 100px for testing, then you'll see if this is what's happening. If yes, you have to make everything a little bit smaller (within a media query) so that it can fit into one line.

Comment: After spending about 8 hours coding today then reading this i feel pretty stupid! Decreased the font size in the media query for portrait mobiles and its spot on now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your social icons are too big, so the entire `<ul>` is wrapping to the next line, but since you have a defined height on the `<footer>` it falls outside of the viewport. Try making your icons smaller, or maybe do something to your `<p>` to have its text wrap two lines in a narrower width.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try putting body tags around everything like

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title></title>
        </head>
        <body class="works_on_smartphone">
        .
        .
        .
        <footer>
        .
        .
        .
        </footer>
        </body>
        </html>
```

This might help.

Another method you might want to look at is using flexbox for you unordered list
as described here: [1]: [Flexbox with Unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406364/flexbox-with-unordered-list)
Charles